# retrieve xml node using linq to xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

```
<book>
    <writer>jhon</writer>
    <descr>
        <title>linq</title>
        <pageno>120</pageno>
    </descr>
    <descr>
        <title>linq1</title>
        <pageno>120</pageno>
     </descr>
</book>
```

i want to retrieve data in the form of  writer and title

jhon linq

jhona linq1

Comment: You will need to explain in more detail what you want to achieve exactly with LINQ to XML. If you want to retrieve a certain node then consider to post a sample of the XML and then explain the criteria for selecting a certain node, then we can help with the LINQ code.

Comment: I edited the question source so that the XML shows up now. However, I still don't see where "jhona" comes from in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

--Assuming that you want the "value" in the writer tag and so on---

*Did you mean to have the xml to be:

```
<book>
 <writer>jhon</writer>
 <descr>
     <title>linq</title>
    <pageno>120</pageno>
 </descr>
 <writer>jhona</writer>
 <descr>
    <title>linq1</title>
     <pageno>120</pageno>
  </descr>
</book>
```

The query will be something like(possible solution)

```
            var Data = (from item in doc.Descendants("book")
                    select new
                    {
                        writer = item.Element("Writer").Value,
                        title = item.Element("title").Value
                    });
```

And then you could concatenate the writer and the title to get the output format you specified(author title)